# using server push methods without browser

Tags: php, javascript, http, websocket, push

I have a client device that request a web page.

I trying to send data to a client when a database table entry is changed.

Problems: the client is not a "browser" ie client side scripting wont do me any good here.(Its a micro controller)

Attempts at first I was thinking of using php and the flush command. I could ever so often output waiting to the client while still in a loop thats checking the database for changes. This to me is a stretch of a method for I don't think my server supports the function and I dont really like it for it seems "dirty" :) ...

Next thought have the php constantly poll the database for changes using a loop. the client should wait until the server finishes and thus I will have a stable connection for "as long as it takes for a change to happen :) optimistic I know". Taking into account that if the connection does time out I can have the client reconnect.

Now a bit of a silly stretch is server side JavaScript a thing lol yes i asked...maybe there is something i don't know about...

I'm hoping someone here can help on this quest of knowledge

Thanks JT

My client is currently:
Opening a socket using tcp connection on port 8090... Then opening a connection to my web site using my socket number and the server address and server port number(80)...I not sure how to correlate this type of socket to the type i would need to stream data very sparingly to the client.

Comment: If it's not a web browser, do you really need to use http? Why not some other protocol more suited for what you need?

Comment: please please do suggest im learning here but im not really aware of an alternate way to poll my database for a change.

Comment: I can currently making http request but its by no means a browser

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is a [socket](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php), which can be kept open. But how you'll implement the client-side depends on what device/software you're using.

Comment: Yea im not sure i could handle this via sockets on the client but ill need to investigate

Comment: most sockets im aware of require a web browser :(

Comment: You seem to be confusing sockets with the JavaScript WebSockets API. Sockets are just some low-level network connections, every major programming language supports them. Even Flash/ActionScript does. On JavaScript, only WebSockets are available (and not on every browser). I'm afraid neither I or anyone else can give you more specific advice if you don't tell us what you're actually using on the client side...

Comment: @bfavaretto i added what the client is lol... Im using a micro controller and essentially doing an HTTP request.

Comment: If you can open a http connection, I'm sure you can open a simple socket too, it's just a matter of finding out how, in whichever language/api combo you are using to program the device.

Comment: @bfavaretto  I am actually currently opening a socket using tcp connection on port 8090... then i open a connection to my web site using my socket number and the server address and server port number(80)...I not sure how to correlate the two though...Im not sure if this "socket" is what you speak of but .... maybe you can clear this up for me

Comment: Yes, that's it. Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php to see how to handle it on the server side. Port 80 is probably already taken by your web server, so you'll have to use a different port. And you'll need a daemon, it can be a simple shell script using php-cli to run a regular php script. If will have to run forever, and keep listening to that port.

Comment: @bfavaretto Trying to bridge these two is very new to me and relly appreciate your help. Do you have any addititional info you would be willing to share or maybe i could offer some rep points in exchange for some more detailed info :)

Comment: I know my php and C syntax !I know my micro controller....not a great on understanding on the server beyond how it handles my php :) I would really appreciate anything you could show me resources sites or just ur knowledge.

Comment: Google gave me some links that should get you started :) See: http://www.funphp.com/?p=33, http://devzone.zend.com/209/writing-socket-servers-in-php/, http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-server.php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336606/explain-basic-php-socket-server-code

Comment: Woshhhhhhhh off to read :) thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to stick with the HTTP protocol (see comments on other possible methods), read about the [meta refresh HTML header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh).  This does what you asked without client side scripting.

Another possible thing would be to setup your db updates as an [RSS feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS).

It does feel better design not to use HTTP.

Non HTTP based notes:

- 1) could you just do your current HTTP request, sleep abit, then repeat the same process?

  - Nothing special, or original; but this fundamentally is what other options are doing.
- 2) using the same socket, blocking reads would allow you to get more data as soon as its available

  - the webserver may need to have the config adjusted to act as streaming media server.
  - [38951](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/38951/is-it-possible-to-stream-music-video-from-an-apache-server)
- As discussion, not a solution, have a look at  [streaming media](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_streaming_media_systems)